# opencv Androidruntime fatal

Tags: android, opencv, google-glass

In the Open cv Tutorial1, i just want to use some Imgproc functions to deal with the input camera images on the callback function: `public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)` . I just added this sentences at `onCameraFram`:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {    
    MatOfPoint corners = null;
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray= inputFrame.gray();
    Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(mGray, corners, 10, 0.5, 0.5);
return mRgba;  
}
```

But when it runs to `Imgpro.goodFeaturesToTrack`, the error jump out on my cell phone and the program stops.

This is the error

```
03-21 11:08:32.519: E/Trace(8212): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-21 11:08:32.972: E/OpenCV_for_Tegra(8212): Tegra Version detected: 0
03-21 11:08:33.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8212): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-405
03-21 11:08:33.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8212): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 11:08:33.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(Imgproc.java:6486)
03-21 11:08:33.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at org.opencv.samples.tutorial1.Tutorial1Activity.onCameraFrame(Tutorial1Activity.java:161)
03-21 11:08:33.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:376)
03-21 11:08:33.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:294)
03-21 11:08:33.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well. here's your 'null pointer' :

```
MatOfPoint corners = null;
```

what you needed, was:

```
MatOfPoint corners = new MatOfPoint();
```